# sanitizing variables with PDO

Tags: php

When using PDO, do i still need to addslashes or is this done already with PDO?

If it's already done, then do is there any other sanitizing i should do before inserting data to a table?

Comment: PDO is no silver bullet. If you do SQL concatenation `name=$name`, instead of using placeholders like `?, name=?, id=? or :name`, then you've achieved nothing.

Comment: I use :name, but what is the different between :name and name=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you definitely do not need `addslashes` if you're using `PDOStatement` properly.  You don't need additional sanitization to prevent SQL injection.  However, you may still want to validate in other ways.  For example, you might check that an email field "looked like" an email address, or make sure that a plain text field did not contain certain characters.  Finally, you may have to escape (e.g. with `htmlspecialchars`) when you output text *from* the database.

Comment: but when i requery the data, I still will need to use stripslashes right?

Comment: @Catfish, no, your database should never contain slash-escaped data.